# Emacs: Program named "virtualenv" does not exist

Tags: python, windows, emacs, virtualenv

I encountered the following error message, when I was in python mode.

```
Error (jedi): Failed to start Jedi EPC server.
*** You may need to run "M-x jedi:install-server". ***
This could solve the problem especially if you haven't run the command yet
since Jedi.el installation or update and if the server complains about
Python module imports.
```

Then I tried `M-x jedi:install-server`. Then it complained that

```
Program named "virtualenv" does not exist
```

Now from the results I got from google, I added the following line to my emacs.d/init.el file, but still I am getting the same error. **Please note that I am using Windows 7**

```
(when (memq window-system '(mac ns))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))
```

Trying to set up jedi in emacs under Windows environment has caused me so much time and trouble already, I just want to complete this once and for all.

Ideally, I am looking for an answer that lists out all the steps I need to setup the virtualenv (on Windows 7) in emacs.

Comment: If you type `M-x describe-variable RET window-system RET` you would not likely return a value of `mac` or `ns`.  `exec-path-from-shell-initialize` is from a library dedicated to OSX, *not* Windows:  https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell  Do you have the executable on your hard drive installed on Windows?

Comment: Are you sure that virtualenv is installed and in you PATH?

Comment: @lawlist I just did `pip install virtualenv` and `which virtualenv` returns `/usr/bin/virtualenv` (all done in cygwin). How should I proceed now ?

Comment: I have no experience with jedi, but the source code appears to be looking for the first element of list of the variable `python-environment-virtualenv`.    This deduction on my part is based on looking at lines 1089 and 1115 of `jedi.el`:  https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi/blob/master/jedi.el  So, my first instinct (without knowing what I'm doing) would be to type:  `M-x describe-variable RET python-environment-virtualenv RET` and see what it says.  Since your executable is in `/usr/bin/`, it would only be found if the car of that list includes `/usr/bin/`.  If it doesn't, then . . .

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem but on Windows 10. I got it working by these steps:

In terminal (cmd/powershell/..):

```
pip install virtualenv
```

After that, in emacs:

```
M-x jedi:install-server
```

And Emacs could install the server.

FYI, I'm running python3.5, pip version 19.2.3, emacs26.2, W10

Answer (score 1):

I think it is clear that `virtualenv` is missing. So you need to do
just two things. With this way you don't bother with PATH variable and all
that.

1. install `virtualenv` however you feel comfortable, (I use `conda` package manager for everything python related and have the installation instructions for that, feel free to use pip or whatever)

   ```
    conda activate yourenv

    conda install virtualenv

    conda list virtualenv #check if virtualenv is actually installed
   ```
2. Find where the `virtualenv` is located (as I use conda, I know the files are in `bin` folder in my installation)
3. and then show `jedi` where `virtualenv` is in emacs `C-h v jedi:environment-virtualenv "~/path-to-conda-env/bin/virtualenv")`. For more help look in the [documentation](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/latest/#configuration) in `Configuration` or
   comment below.
4. `M-x jedi:install-server` in emacs
5. Test on a `.py` file.

Comment: If you are using Conda anyway for other reasons, this makes sense; but to recommend it for someone who is currently using a different package manager, it's huge overkill for this particular problem.

Comment: I mean I am just showing a way to install `virtualenv` right? Up to you what package manager you use. The previous answer suggesting using pip for example.

Comment: Imagine you are a beginner who doesn't know what Conda is and somehow ends up embarking on a quest to take it into use so that they can resolve this problem in accordance with your instructions. Your answer should really point out why they might not want to.

Comment: I am so sorry. How would you advice I change the answer? Should I put a warning on top or delete the answer or? I have updated the answer trying to make it a bit "friendlier". Please let me know. Your concern is much appreciated.

Comment: I guess this comment thread and your recent changes should be enough to give anyone enough warning. (Though these comments could be deleted eventually.)